# Github merge to behind branch

Tags: git, github

So I just had a quick question surrounding Github and pulling and branches and stuff. So I was wondering what the procedure would be when 2 people are working on a a project in this situation.

So say there are 3 branches: master, firstBranch and secondBranch. firstBranch and secondBranch are both being worked on. When firstBranch merges with master to push their code into the master branch, what should the person working on secondBranch do so when they merge there aren't conflicts? If they pull the main branch that is fine, but the code they are working on in the secondBranch will be outdated still?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Actually, your scenario isn't really limited to just two branches, because in theory *anyone* could be adding new commits to `master` as you are working on `secondBranch`.  The general way to handle this is to either merge or rebase `secondBranch` on `master`.

```
# for merging, from secondBranch
git fetch origin
git merge origin/master

# for rebasing, again from secondBranch
git fetch origin
git rebase origin/master
```

The `git fetch origin` command is necessary to bring your local tracking branches up to date, specifically to bring `origin/master` up to date with whatever the latest work on the remote might be.  Note that when using either merge or rebase, there is the potential for merge conflicts.  You would have to resolve those before proceeding.